# How can I fetch the last-modified value of a remote file?

Tags: vb.net, url, last-modified

I'd like to know the last-modifed date of a remote file (defined via url).
And only download it, if it's newer than my locally stored one.

I managed to do that for local files, but can't find a solution to do that for remote files (without downloading them)

working:

```
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:/test.txt")
MsgBox("File was last modified on " & infoReader.LastWriteTime)
```

not working:

```
        Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("http://google.com/robots.txt")
        MsgBox("File was last modified on " & infoReader.LastWriteTime)
```

I'd love to have a solution which will only have to download the headers of a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class to fetch the last modified date from the server.  Because it's sending a `HEAD` request, it will not fetch the file contents:

```
Dim client = New HttpClient()
Dim msg = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, "http://google.com/robots.txt")
Dim resp = client.SendAsync(msg).Result
Dim lastMod = resp.Content.Headers.LastModified
```

You could also use the `If-Modified-Since` request header with a `GET` request.  This way the response should be `304 - Not Modified` if the file has not been changed (no file content sent), or `200 - OK` if the file has been changed (and the contents of the file will be sent in the response), although the server is not required to honor this header.

```
Dim client = New HttpClient()
Dim msg = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://google.com/robots.txt")
msg.Headers.IfModifiedSince = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1) ' use the date of your copy of the file
Dim resp = client.SendAsync(msg).Result
Select Case resp.StatusCode
    Case HttpStatusCode.NotModified
        ' Your copy is up-to-date
    Case HttpStatusCode.OK
        ' Your copy is out of date, so save it
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\robots.txt", resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync.Result)
End Select
```

Note the use of `.Result`, since I was testing in a console application - you should probably `await` instead.

Comment: Can you think of a solution which doesn't require azure? (installing it right now, will test your solution then)

Comment: @Wurstbro I don't know why this would require Azure - just a reference to System.Net.Http.dll, which is included in .NET 4.5, or the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package if targeting .NET 4.0.  What are you seeing that requires Azure - I think I have the SDK installed, so I could be referencing something without realizing.

Comment: well, System.Net.Http doesn't exist in my enviroment. I have HttpListener etc. but no blank Http

Comment: @Wurstbro What version of .NET are you targeting for your project?

Comment: 4.5.1 windows forms application

Comment: @Wurstbro And you have added System.Net.Http.dll to the project references?

Answer (score 1):

If the server offers it, you can get it through the [HTTP header Last-Modified property](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29). But your still stuck at downloading the full file.

You could get it through FTP.
See if the server allows you to see the list of files in a folder.
If the website offer the date somewhere that you could pull through screen scrapping.

Comment: Mark's solution is better, but thank you nethertheless

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little bit old question but, there's still a better answer.

```
            Dim req As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("someurl")
            req.Method = "HEAD"
            Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
            Dim remoteFileLastModified As String = resp.Headers.Get("Last-Modified")
            Dim remoteFileLastModifiedDateTime As DateTime
            If DateTime.TryParse(remoteFileLastModified, remoteFileLastModifiedDateTime) Then
                MsgBox("Date Last Modified:" + remoteFileLastModifiedDateTime.ToString("d MMMM yyyy dddd HH:mm:ss"))
            Else
                MsgBox("could not determine")
            End If
```